# How to fix Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

This question is seems to be already answered but my scenario is different. I am getting  Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 everytime. Can anyone help me to fix this.Thanks

here is my code

```
function send()
{

    let detail = new FormData();
    detail.append("start",true);
    detail.append("user",'david');
   
postRequest("https://myjson-url/game.php?"
,detail, getData);

}

function getData(res)
{

    let data = JSON.parse(res);
    console.log(data);

}
//async function
  async function checkStatus(res) {
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(await res.text());
    }
    return res;
  }

//my post request

    function postRequest(url, info, func){
        fetch(url, {method: "POST", body: info})
        .then(checkStatus)
        .then(func)
        .catch(console.error);
    }
```

Comment: Put your `console.log` above your `JSON.parse` and make sure you are getting a valid `JSON` response.

Comment: How about fixing `game.php` so that it returns valid JSON.

Comment: @RyanWilson Thanks for your response. Yes I just did I am getting console message but the rest of the JSON.parse is not working..

Comment: @user3718511 If it's returning valid `JSON` you wouldn't be getting an error.

Comment: and here we go again...

Comment: @RyanWilson game.php is retruning valid json.I mean there is no issue with it but issue I am getting on client site when I am trying to post and then accessing it.Please help if u have clue.Thanks

Comment: @user3718511 How about you update your post with the "valid" `json` which you are getting client side from the server???

Comment: @RyanWilson I think I failed to clear it. I mean I have tested game.php using postman there is valid response. But I am not getting response using JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add json()
let data = res.json();

Answer (score 13):

It could be that in `getData(res)`  the `res` is already a parsed JSON object so this line is not necessary :

```
let data = JSON.parse(res);
```

Try change it to

```
let data = res;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried but its not working..I am only getting response message from Response {type: "cors", url: "https://myjson-url/game.php?", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}

Comment: @user3718511 what do you expect to be getting? Does the response or ```res``` variable have a ```res.body``` attribute?

Comment: Does the ```res.body``` attribute contain the data you want to get from the server?

Comment: yes it is. Thats why I am confused why its not working..

Comment: JSON.parse() only parses a string into a javascript object. But res is already a javascript object. So it gives an error when trying to parse it. Res is not a string.

Comment: I have figured it out. let data = res.json() now I am getting json data..